# Why does times argument in rep function not behaving correctly

Tags: r, arguments, rep

The answer to this question maybe very simple but I cannot think of obvious reasons for this.

Why does `rep(1,40*(1-0.8))` result in vector of length 7 instead of 8?  Anyone please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to floating point precision:

```
print(40*(1-0.8), digits = 20)
## [1] 7.9999999999999982
```

`round` can be used:

```
rep(1, round(40*(1-0.8)))
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: I assumed so, but I am still confused! Why 0.2*40 is not a whole number?

Comment: try  print(1-0.8, digits = 20)

Comment: @AnilGoyal I've marked the question as a duplicate of a FAQ - see the FAQ for a quite detailed description of why `.2 * 40` is not a whole number.

Comment: 0.2 * 40 is a whole number but 1-0.8 is not exactly 0.2